# How to get the pk of several objects in the domain name url www.site.com in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I try to build a blog and this blog in the home view `www.site.com` consist of posts and these posts have comments, Now I Show the posts using List [] because the user has the ability to follow the content and in this list, I show the content based on the user, Now I successfully to show the posts but this post contains comments that's mean I need to get the pk of the post but as I said this post in the home view `www.site.com` without any extra URL that's mean as My knowledge I can't pass the pk in the `def  home_screen_view(request, pk)` because this raise error **home_screen_view() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'pk'**

#### So my qustion how can I get the pk in the base url `www.site.com`

My view

```
def home_screen_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
        post = []
        for u in users:
            p = Account.objects.get(username=u)
            posts = p.post_set.all()
            post.append(posts)
        my_posts = request.user.post_set.all()
        post.append(my_posts)
        if len(post):
            post= sorted(chain(*post), reverse=True, key=lambda post: post.created_date)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(pk=post.pk)  # here I want to get the pk of the post in order to show the comments related this post
        comment = PostCommentIDE.objects.filter(post=posts)
```

The url

```
path('', home_screen_view, name='home'),
```

My Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo_article = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_poster_filepath)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My Comment Model

```
class PostCommentIDE(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ide_com')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The post template

```
{% for post in posts %}
  ...
#here I want to render the comments that related to spesific post
            {% for comment in comments %}
                {{ comments.content }}
             {% endfor %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

I use function based view

Comment: Can't you in your template do `{% for comment in post.ide_com.all %}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your home_screen_view you can remove

```
comment = PostCommentIDE.objects.filter(post=posts)
```

Instead, in your template you can do:

```
{% for comment in post.ide_com.all %}
    {{ comments.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Explanation:**

Your comment model `PostCommentIDE` has a ForeignKey relationship with `Post`. This enables you to get the related comments for a post. By default you could have accessed the comments with `post.postcommentide_set.all`, but as you've defined a related_name attribute on that relationship, it becomes `post.ide_com.all`.  Read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls

Comment: Can you please, clarify how this `post.ide_com.all` come

Comment: @Ahmed of course, I'll add it to this answer